# Why can't I set the XDocument XDeclaration encoding type to iso-8859-1?

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, linq-to-xml

Why doesn't the following code set the XML declaration encoding type?  It always sets the encoding to utf-16 instead. Am I missing something very obvious?

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
  new XDeclaration("1.0", "iso-8859-1", null), 
  new XElement("root", "")
);
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root></root>
```

Comment: Check the encoding of the `TextWriter` you're using. See [here](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2008/08/19/xml-declarations-in-linq-to-xml.aspx). If the above link isn't working, a [Google cache version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.alexthissen.nl%2Fblogs%2Fmain%2Farchive%2F2008%2F08%2F19%2Fxml-declarations-in-linq-to-xml.aspx) may still be available [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.alexthissen.nl%2Fblogs%2Fmain%2Farchive%2F2008%2F08%2F19%2Fxml-declarations-in-linq-to-xml.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the answer about specifying the `TextWriter`'s encoding.

As an aside: `ISO-8859-1` is a character-set, not an encoding. `Unicode` is also a character-set, but `UTF-16` is an encoding of the `Unicode` character set into a sequence of bytes. You cannot specify a document's encoding as `ISO-8859-1`, just as you cannot specify a document's character-set as `UTF-16`. Note that `Unicode` is the native character-set and `UTF-16` is the native `Unicode` encoding for both .NET and Java `String` classes and text-based or string-based operations.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to specify an invalid encoding using XDocument? I'm submitting XML to a third party who require the incorrect declaration <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>.

Comment: I'm sure you can. What system out there conforms to proper usage, language, and spec?

Answer (score 4):

As stated, the .NET XML/Stream writing implementation 'picks up' or interprets the encoding from somewhere other than the declared XML encoding. I have successfully tested a working solution, as described at the URL contained within the earlier [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1543428/304330)

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "no"), 
        new XElement("foo", "bar"));

MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(memstream, new UTF8Encoding());

//'Write' (save) XDocument XML to MemoryStream-backed XmlTextWriter instance
xmlDoc.Save(xmlwriter);

//Read back XML string from stream
xmlwriter.Flush();    
memstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  //OR "stream.Position = 0"
StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(memstream);
string xml = streamreader.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(xml);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I somehow can't find any working answer here, so here is an actual solution which will output the wanted encoding in the header:

```
    private void CreateXml()
    {       
        XmlTextWriter xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter("c:\\test.xml", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));        

        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
          new XElement("Test")
        );

        xdoc.Save(xmlwriter);
        xmlwriter.Close();
    }
```

The reason why you are getting UTF-16 is that strings are encoded with UTF-16 in memory, and as long as you don't specify an encoding for the output of the XML, it will override the encoding in the XML header to match the actual encoding being used. Using an `XmlTextWriter` is one method of specifying a different encoding.

You can also let the `XmlTextWriter` write to a `MemoryStream` and then transform it back to `string` if you need to perform the whole operation in memory.