# how to convert xml to string including declaration

Tags: c#, xml, string, linq

i have to convert an xml into string

The xml is created as:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = new System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(new System.Xml.Linq.XDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1",""));
System.Xml.Linq.XElement root = new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("qcs");
System.Xml.Linq.XElement goal_Name = new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("goal", new System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute("name","abc"));
root.Add(goal_Name);
doc.Add(root);
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

I am getting string as:

```
<qcs>
  <goal name="Goal15">
  </goal>
</qcs>
```

But skipping declaration part which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

I need string as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<qcs>
  <goal name="Goal15">
    <value action="A">0.85</value>
    <value action="B">0.87</value>
  </goal>
```

I need to have this too in string. 
How to do that?

Comment: The link to the duplicate question is at the top of your post.

Comment: the link above is not helping. it is converting string to xml including declaration but its putting declaration as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> but i want <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
XElement root = new XElement("qcs");
XElement goal_Name = new XElement("goal", new System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute("name", "abc"));
root.Add(goal_Name);

XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", string.Empty), root);

var wr = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(wr);
Console.Write(wr.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: it works but after converting to string its showing declaration as<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> but it actually is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> sorry i had to unmark your answer..

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543363/why-cant-i-set-the-xdocument-xdeclaration-encoding-type-to-iso-8859-1

Comment: i am also creating the xml file it is having <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> in document..so i think i will had to add this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> my self along with doc.ToString() to get desired output..