# .NET: How to write an empty XML node as "<node></node>" rather than "<node />"

Tags: .net, xml

I'm building an xml document in .net using the usual objects (`XmlDocument`, `XmlElement`, etc) finally outputting it as a string (`xmlDocument.OuterXml`).

In the final output all the empty xml elements without an innerXml get written like this-- `<node />`

While I specifically need them to be written like this-- `<node></node>`

Is there a way to do this with .NET objects? I suppose I could replace the relevant elements in the final string with Regex, but I was hoping for a cleaner method.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an empty text node to the empty elements.

Here is an example using `XDocument`:

```cs
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("root", new XElement("test", "hello world"), new XElement("foobar", new XElement("empty"), new XElement("has_attrs", new XAttribute("test", "123")))));
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

> ```
> <root>
>   <test>hello world</test>
>   <foobar>
>     <empty />
>     <has_attrs test="123" />
>   </foobar>
> </root>
> ```

```cs
foreach (var empty in doc.Descendants().Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value) && !e.Attributes().Any()))
{
    empty.Add(string.Empty);
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

> ```
> <root>
>   <test>hello world</test>
>   <foobar>
>     <empty></empty>
>     <has_attrs test="123" />
>   </foobar>
> </root>
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Keith. It's progress, but the above code changes all the nodes, including the ones with attributes, while I require only those truly empty. Another problem is that the Xdocument changes the encoding, but maybe I could figure that one out.

Comment: @Indigo121 I have updated my answer to leave nodes with attributes alone. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543363/why-cant-i-set-the-xdocument-xdeclaration-encoding-type-to-iso-8859-1) will help with encoding.

Comment: Thanks again, Keith. I will try this.